# Why not to enable Symfony debug tools in production?

Tags: php, debugging, symfony, exception

I often find really useful to convert php errors to exceptions registering callbacks to `set_error_handler` and `register_shutdown_function`, so i decided to give a try to some more solid solution, namely the Symfony Debug component. However, in the [introduction page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug/introduction.html) they warn:

> You should never enable the debug tools in a production environment as they might disclose sensitive information to the user.

Enabling the debug component basically means to call `Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug::enable()`, which in turn [registers an error handler and an exception handler](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Debug/Debug.html). This also let the developer choose to `$displayErrors`, which means

> Whether to display errors (for development) or just log them (for production)

So one could simply [register some custom logger](https://github.com/symfony/Debug/blob/master/ErrorHandler.php#LC108) and use the debugger safely in production, isn't it?

I'd really like to start using this component to safely manage error situations in php, just because i was starting to reinvent the wheel, writing something really close to that (except for quality of course :D), but that advice not to use it in production worries me a little: what kind of problems could arise from it in your opinion?

By the way, displaying errors means this: [`$exceptionHandler = set_exception_handler('var_dump');`](https://github.com/symfony/Debug/blob/master/ErrorHandler.php#LC152), so it should be perfectly fine to set `$displayErrors` on during development, and then turn it off in production, keeping the safety of having an error handler catching all errors as exceptions and logging them down.

So how do you use this component in production (if you do it at all)?

Comment: I think this warning by the developpers is about the debug toolbar (/app_dev.php/) that should indeed *never* be accessible in production. It would allow any user to display critical information about your application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should "[use] this component to safely manage error situations in php".
Basically, these exceptions you get are not meant to be caught at all. They are meant to be fixed right now, and to block the development until you do. In the old days, you could get hundreds of notices on the same page and ignore them because your error reporting level was too low for them.

The exceptions you can catch in your code are all the other exceptions, that are not converted from php errors. Everything else is something that needs to be fixed, preferably during development. If such an errors occurs in production, it must not slow down the execution or display debug information, that's why it is disabled in my opinion.

Comment: I see your point and i mostly agree with you. However, i was thinking about this kind of situation: say i am building a service that manages files in some way, and it expects some file to be in place; say i have done all checks (file exists, is readable, etc..) but nevertheless `fopen` fails for some reason (maybe some random failure has happened), then a PHP error is thrown. I cannot be sure in development that this is not going to happen, even more so if i am developing an unattended command-line service, instead of a classic site.

Comment: To add to my last comment, it has happened to me that while deploying a site with Filezilla, a bug related to character encoding (it seemed) happened, and a php file inside the server ended up lacking a slash character that was there to close a multi-line comment. I was able to track down the bug adding a `register_shutdown_function`(it was a simple WordPress site, lacking these kinds of checks) and printing the error. This was definitely a situation where i would want to have an error-checking mechanism showing a nice "server error page", instead of a blank page.

Comment: `fopen` returns false on error, which means you'll be able to handle this kind of situation. As of libraries, they'll throw their own exceptions, which you can catch. For instance, the Filesystem component of Symfony throws IOExceptions . Plus you can't handle all errors : "The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called. ", which means you should customize your blank page anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think that `DebugClassLoader::enable();` which is inside `Debug::enable()` shouldn't be called in production.

Apart from that the first part of function with error and exception handler should be fine in production.